# Can I use DllImport function in ASP.NET web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to use DllImport function (such as [DllImport("wininet.dll")] ) in my web application. I also use in my windows form application. Normally can i use it ?

Advance thanks for answer.

Comment: If your `Deploy Server` is a Windows Server and has the DLL located in System32 it should work.

Comment: Add `using System.Runtime.InteropServices` on your model/controller code and you can use `[DllImport("wininet.dll")]` in Windows server. Note that the field/variable using the attribute must be declared with `extern`, e.g. `private extern static bool GetConnectionState`.

Comment: Thanks but can I use any dll import ?